# How to access, merge and collect array values within a nested data structure by different criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, find, mapping

I have below array of objects. As you can see, i have 2 runTypes named `VEGGIES` and `FRUITS`. Each `runType` will have a list of verticals to it. For e.g. `VEGGIES` has `SPINACH, TOMATO, ONION` and FRUITS has `APPLE, BANANA, GRAPES`

```
let data = [
  {
    "runType": "VEGGIES",
    "verticals": [
      { 
        "vertical": "SPINACH",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "TOMATO",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "ONION",
        "radars": {}
      },
    ],
    "total_count": {}
  },
  {
    "runType": "FRUITS",
    "verticals": [
      {
        "vertical": "APPLE",
        "radars": {
           
         }
      },
      {
        "vertical": "BANANA",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "GRAPES",
        "radars": {
          "P5": 8
        }
      }
    ],
    "total_count": {
      "P5": 8
    }
  }
]
```

In my case, i want to extract these `vertical` values and put them in an array. In case of regular array of objects, we can achieve the above task by using this code.

```
let result = data.map(({ verticals }) => vertical)
```

But my code has array of objects inside an array of object. Can someone please let me know how to achieve these 3 scenarios

1. Scenario 1- Get all the verticals for both runType. Result should be
   [SPINACH, TOMATO, ONION, APPLE, BANANA, GRAPES]
2. Scenario 2- get all verticals for runType = 'VEGGIES'. Result should be
   [SPINACH, TOMATO, ONION]
3. Scenario 3- get all verticals for runType = 'FRUITS'. Result should be
   [APPLE, BANANA, GRAPES]

Can someone pls shed some light on this particular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the OP also might have a look into [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ... [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is also worth a try ...

```js
let data = [{
  "runType": "VEGGIES",
  "verticals": [{ 
    "vertical": "SPINACH",
    "radars": {},
  }, {
    "vertical": "TOMATO",
    "radars": {},
  }, {
    "vertical": "ONION",
    "radars": {},
  }],
  "total_count": {},
}, {
  "runType": "FRUITS",
  "verticals": [{
    "vertical": "APPLE",
    "radars": {},
  }, {
    "vertical": "BANANA",
    "radars": {},
  }, {
    "vertical": "GRAPES",
    "radars": {
      "P5": 8,
    },
  }],
  "total_count": {
    "P5": 8,
  },
}];

// Scenario 1
// - Get all the verticals for both runType.
//   - Result should be [SPINACH, TOMATO, ONION, APPLE, BANANA, GRAPES]
console.log('Scenario 1 ... ', data

  .flatMap(({ verticals }) =>
    verticals.map(({ vertical }) => vertical)
  )
);

// Scenario 2
// - get all verticals for runType = 'VEGGIES'.
//   - Result should be [SPINACH, TOMATO, ONION]
console.log('Scenario 2 ... ', data

  .find(item => item.runType === 'VEGGIES')
  .verticals.map(({ vertical }) => vertical)
);

// Scenario 3
// - get all verticals for runType = 'FRUITS'.
//   - Result should be [APPLE, BANANA, GRAPES]
console.log('Scenario 3 ... ', data

  .find(item => item.runType === 'FRUITS')
  .verticals.map(({ vertical }) => vertical)
);


// Bonus
// - based on Array#reduce one can achieve everything at once

function groupMergeAndCollectVerticals(collector, item) {
  const { index, list } = collector;
  const { runType, verticals } = item;

  const group = (index[runType] ??= []);
  const verticalList = verticals.map(({ vertical }) => vertical);

  group.push(...verticalList);
  list.push(...verticalList);

  return collector;
}
const verticalsCollection =
  data.reduce(groupMergeAndCollectVerticals, { index: {}, list: [] });

console.log(
  'reduce based :: all at once ... ',
  verticalsCollection
);
console.log(
  'reduce based :: Scenario 1 ... ',
  verticalsCollection.list
);
console.log(
  'reduce based :: Scenario 2 ... ',
  verticalsCollection.index['VEGGIES']
);
console.log(
  'reduce based :: Scenario 3 ... ',
  verticalsCollection.index['FRUITS']
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let data = [{
    "runType": "VEGGIES",
    "verticals": [{
        "vertical": "SPINACH",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "TOMATO",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "ONION",
        "radars": {}
      },
    ],
    "total_count": {}
  },
  {
    "runType": "FRUITS",
    "verticals": [{
        "vertical": "APPLE",
        "radars": {

        }
      },
      {
        "vertical": "BANANA",
        "radars": {}
      },
      {
        "vertical": "GRAPES",
        "radars": {
          "P5": 8
        }
      }
    ],
    "total_count": {
      "P5": 8
    }
  }
]

var findData = (runType) => data.filter(x => x.runType == runType).map(x => x.verticals)[0].map(i => i.vertical)

console.log("VEGGIES:", findData("VEGGIES"))
console.log("FRUITS:", findData("FRUITS"))
console.log("COMBINED:", findData("VEGGIES").concat(findData("FRUITS")))
```